# Solving limit with two unknown constants

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the constants $A$ and $B$ if $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+x}-Ax-B\right) = 0\;\;\;\;?$$

I'm not sure how I might get the answer for two unknowns with one equation.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking I had to write is as a fraction where the denominator goes to infinity and numerator doesn't, so I tried multuplying, diving with the conjugate but the numerator still had x with a higher power.

Comment: Replace $x+1/2$ by $y$. So you have $\lim_{y\to\infty} \sqrt{y^2-1/4}-A(y-1/2)-B =0 $.

Comment: No, thanks for the help Darshan

Comment: @Olp112 No, Asked just I wonder if I missed something.....

Comment: Nothing is missing, I can only accept one answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to find the asymptote of $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ at infinity. The standard method is to say that if
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}-Ax-B = 0$$
then surely also
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}-Ax-B}{x} = 0$$
which implies
$$A = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}=1$$
So $A=1$ and now you can substitute this back into the original equation to find $B$.

Comment: May I know how can I find the value of $B$ after substituting for the value of $A = 1$?

Comment: @DarshanP. We can use $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ to get $B=\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-x = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, that's true, Nice! $\to + 1$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 + x} - Ax - B
& = \lim_{x \to \infty}x\sqrt{1 + \frac 1x} - Ax - B\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} x \left( 1+ \frac 12\frac 1x + ..........\text{terms with higher power of }\frac 1x\right) - Ax - B\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(x +  \frac 12......\text{terms tending zero as x will tend to infinity}\right) - Ax - B\\
& = 0 \text{ given}\\
\implies A =1 \text{ and } B = \frac 12
\end{align*}$$

- How and why can I expand $\sqrt {1 + \frac 1x}$?
  Because the expansion of $(1+\delta)^{\frac 12} $ is allowed if $\delta$ is really a $\delta$ (I mean small) which here $\frac 1x$ tends to be very small as $x\to\infty$. So yes! we are good to expand.

Comment: Though the solution may look good, I still wonder if the limit will always be a negative zero (I mean $0^-$)

Comment: Why is B=1/2? x-Ax-B=0, I understand why A=1 but why B=1/2?

Comment: You can right it as as $$(x + \frac 12 ........\text{terms tending zero}) - Ax - B = (x - Ax) + (\frac 12 - B) + \text{terms tending to zero}$$ now in order to have the answer of limit as zero we must have the value of $A = 1$ and $B = \frac 12$ and rest of terms will tend to zero so as in net our answer of limit will also be zero.

Answer (score 1):

$((x+1/2)^2-1/4)^{1/2}-Ax-B;$

Set $y:=x+1/2,$ and consider $y \rightarrow \infty$.

$(y^2-1/4)^{1/2}-A(y-1/2)-B;$

The asymptote of $(y^2-1/4)^{1/2}$ is $y$.

Collecting corresponding terms in the asymptotic expression:

$y(1-A)+((1/2)A-B) =0$ we get

$A=1$ and $B=1/2.$